# Array of objects inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got this object. I want to add a 'accelerationHistory' to them, so I had this brilliant idea of making it's acceleration object an array.

```
var connectedEstimotes = [{
id : 'n/a',
temp : 'n/a',
acceleration: [{x:'n/a',y:'n/a',z:'n/a'}],
isMoving : 'notSure',
batt : 'n/a',
motionStateDuration : { current:{number:'n/a',unit:'n/a'},previous:{number:'n/a',unit:'n/a'}},
cont : 0,
}];
```

I'm accessing it's properties this way:

```
        connectedEstimotes[index] = estimotesplugin.nearableStuff(data);
        //Only the info that needs postprocessing is being updated afterwards
        connectedEstimotes[index].temp = Math.round((estimotesplugin.nearableStuff(data).temp) * 10) / 10;
        connectedEstimotes[index].acceleration.z = (estimotesplugin.nearableStuff(data).acceleration.z) + 980;
        connectedEstimotes[index].batt = Math.round((estimotesplugin.nearableStuff(data).batt) * 10) / 10;
```

Everything works fine but whenever I try this:

`connectedEstimotes[index].acceleration.push(estimotesplugin.nearableStuff(data).acceleration)`

It returns:

`TypeError: connectedEstimotes[index].acceleration.push is not a function`

If I try to make

```
var thisCont = connectedEstimotes[index].cont;
connectedEstimotes[index].acceleration[thisCont] = (estimotesplugin.nearableStuff(data).acceleration)
thisCont++;
```

I get that thisCont is NaN, altho If I make this next thing, it works (but it's of no use for me, obiously).

```
connectedEstimotes[index].acceleration[0] = (estimotesplugin.nearableStuff(data).acceleration)
thisCont++;
```

Somebody help, plz? Is there a better way to keep track of history of values of this?

Comment: By doing `connectedEstimotes[index].acceleration.z = ...`, this seems to imply that you want the `acceleration` property to be used as an *object* rather than an array, but the array item you listed first looks to have an array for `acceleration`?

Comment: I'm not getting the same problem...when I try to .push( /*some object*/) it works just fine. Maybe double check your syntax?

Comment: Need a [MCVE] - the `connectedEstimotes` array you posted *does* have an item whose `acceleration` property is an array, but your error `acceleration.push is not a function` implies that, at some point, the property is *not* an array, but there's not enough code here to figure out why

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm receiving the whole object properties since `connectedEstimotes[index] = estimotesplugin.nearableStuff(data);` and even If I comment out that line or the one you mention, I get the same error. `push is not a function.`

Comment: Well whatever is causing it, it means at that point is not an Array. Try to define it using `const` so you see when the Array reference is lost.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks! I've found the issue, I'll post it right away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CertainPerformance comment I found out that my template object

```
var connectedEstimotes = [{
id : 'n/a',
temp : 'n/a',
acceleration: [{x:'n/a',y:'n/a',z:'n/a'}],
isMoving : 'notSure',
batt : 'n/a',
motionStateDuration : { current:{number:'n/a',unit:'n/a'},previous:    {number:'n/a',unit:'n/a'}},
cont : 0,
}];
```

Has indeed an array of objects inside, but when I filled it with `estimotesplugin.nearableStuff(data)` acceleration became a simple object inside this array of objects.

Had to export acceleration as an array from `estimotesplugin`.

In the function inside estimotesplugin I had:

```
var acceleration = {
        x: data.readInt8(16) * 15.625,
        y: data.readInt8(17) * 15.625,
        z: data.readInt8(18) * 15.625
    };
return {
    id,
    temp,
    acceleration,
    isMoving,
    batt,
    motionStateDuration,
}
```

So I had to...

```
var acceleration = [{
        x: data.readInt8(16) * 15.625,
        y: data.readInt8(17) * 15.625,
        z: data.readInt8(18) * 15.625
    }];
```

(Mind the new square bracket)

Answer (score 1):

The `push` method only works when the acceleration object is already an array. Right now you are doing this:

```
connectedEstimotes[index].acceleration.z = (estimotesplugin.nearableStuff(data).acceleration.z) + 980;
```

At this point the acceleration object is a normal object with property `z` e.g.

```
connectedEstimates[index].acceleration = { z: 980 };
```

What you want however, is `acceleration` to be an array `[]`.

You can `[].push(x)` but you cannot `{ z: 980 }.push()`.

Comment: Problem was that estimotesplugin was exporting acceleration as an object, not as an array of objects. :)

Comment: Actually your comment helped as well! Since I now receive an array, If I assign `connectedEstimotes[index].acceleration.z = (estimotesplugin.nearableStuff(data).acceleration.z) + 980;` I lose again my array type.